# OSX El Capitan C++ boost and Xcode fails building project

Tags: python, c++, xcode, macos, boost

I have been desperately looking around the internet to find a workaround for my C++ boost project to work on my OSX El Captian. here is the simple code I'm trying to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Keeps failing to with this ERROR:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"__Py_NoneStruct", referenced from:
  boost::python::api::object::object() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have installed boost library via homebrew and defined the correct Header and Lib path in my Xcode project. 
I also tried different combination of build settings hoping the project would build. NO LUCK!!!
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you compile the Boost::Pyhton library? It is not a header-only library, and it must be compiled from source. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/building.html for more details.

Comment: @vsoftco, So which path exactly should I include? Path to the actual boost or boost-python

Comment: Check [this link](http://www.shocksolution.com/python-basics-tutorials-and-examples/linking-python-and-c-with-boostpython/), it may help. Make sure you use `-lboost-python` in your compile line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you have installed boost using homebrew like this

```
brew install boost-python
```

otherwise the installed boost doesn't have the boost python library.

Then you need to add

```
-lboost_python
```

in your compile script

and also link to `python` libraries as well. To link to python you may need to pass

```
-lpython
```

too.

Comment: thanks! Im using Xcode, do you know where exactly should those extra parameters go? Like -lboost-python and -lpython

Comment: @mehdix_ I believe you should find it under `build settings` searching for  `other linker flags`

Comment: @mehdix_ please up vote if this has solved your problem.